# css and min js is not getting apply after add data in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

i want to add data and that data i'm showing on list. but the problem is happening with me  when i added data through ajax so in success function after show alert like "successfully added" i wrote location.relode() so it went to home page (div tag data-role="page") rather than current page. when i replace that relode function with like window.location.hash='#id_of_myDiv_page'.. so it showing data fine but  css and min js (CDN) is not working and thats why list tag is looking very big  ..this is my big issue.

**My code**

```
 $("#b4").click(function (){         
       $.ajax({
         type:"POST",                                    url:"http://manoj/adddoc.php",
                   data: $("#frm1").serialize(),                        
                   success:function(response)
                   {                       
                      if(response== 1)
                         {    alert("Record Added Succesfully");
                               managedoctor();  **calling function**
                            window.location.hash='#managedoctor'; 
                            }                            
                       else
                           alert("error while adding the data");                      
                        }                          
                  });  
                  });
                }   
 function managedoctor()
{
         $.ajax({
          async:true, 
             type:"GET",
             url:"http://manoj/doctor_details.php",
             dataType:'JSON',                
             success:function(response)
             {
                  var list="";
                   if(response.length !=0){ 
                  for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++) 
                    { 
                    list+='<li doc_id="'+response[i].id+'"><img src="doctor.png"/><p><h3><a href="#adddoc" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="flip" id="'+response[i].id+'">'+response[i].docname+'</a></h3></p></li>';
                       }    
                    }
                    if(list!="")
                    {
                     $("#myListView").html(list);   

                    } 
                         }
                         });    
 **html page**
         <div data-role="page" id="managedoctor" data-theme="b" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <a id="refreshdoctor" href="#adddoc" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="flip">Add Doctor</a>
       </div>
      <div id="doctorlist">
           <ul id="myListView" data-inset="true" data-role="listview"  data-theme="c"  data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search doctors..." style="margin-top:30px!important;">
              </ul>  </div>       
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#myListView").listview( "refresh" );
```

Source:
http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/